# How to customize pagination links in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I'd like to customize the pagination link template in buddypress.

Currently, the pagination does not show up to 10 page links even though total page count is more than 10.

The template looks like following.

`1 2 ... 10 ->`

I want to show all page numbers from 1 to 10.

How can I customize this using plugin or modifying theme?

Thank you.

Andriy